# Changed my code from completion to async and with the same decoding method i get this error

Tags: swift, async-await, completion

I had this code before using completion and it worked and still works perfectly:

```swift
func fetchUser(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping(UserModel) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
        .document(uid)
        .getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}
            
            guard let user = try? snapshot.data(as: UserModel.self) else {return}
            
            completion(user)
        }
}
```

but when i switched to async / await i get this error:

> Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.

With this code:

```swift
func fetchUser(withUid uid: String) async throws -> UserModel {
    do {
        let snapshot = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument()
        do {
            let user = try snapshot.data(as: UserModel.self)
            return user
        } catch {
            throw(error)
        }
    } catch {
        throw(error)
    }
}
```

Any tips on where i went wrong?

Switched to `async` code and got an error with decoding

Comment: Are you sure about the original version? it seems you are ignoring the error in that by using `try?`

Comment: On the initial code, either write `try!` instead of `try?`, or use a proper `do`/`catch`, but you new code shouldn't create error, it should just highlight a previous error you ignored with `try?` (with a question mark), and that the `completion` wasn't called.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but you can remove all `do - catch` blocks as the method explicitly `throws`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yes i only returned nil and handled the error where this fetchUser() is called, it's been working fine until i added all the async stuff

Comment: @Larme hmm very weird but the decoding been working fine with the previous code

Comment: @vadian i still have to use do-catch to get the snapshot and throw if there is an error no?

Comment: No, the errors are handed over to the caller. Removing the `do - catch` blocks does exactly the same as your code.

Comment: `do { try ... } catch { throw theExactErrorThrownByTheTryWithNothingElse }`, that's the same as `try ...`. If you were to add some log, throw a custom error computed or not from the error thrown by the catch, yes, it'd be different, but currently, no.

Comment: Ohh okay thank you guys! Did that and still have the same error so it must be from the UserModel struct but i don't understand it's the same used in the completion and it works.. Guess il revise this all thank you!

Comment: As said, if you still have the previous code, don't use `try?`, it still should be there. We can't guess why there is that error... Did you changed something on your model Firebase?

Answer (score 2):

We are comparing apples to oranges here, because your completion handler rendition is not reporting errors, but rather just doing an immediate `return` without calling the completion handler. So you might be failing in the completion handler pattern without ever knowing, which is what I suspect is happening here.

Here is the standard completion handler pattern with a [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type that handles both `.success` and `.failure`:

```swift
func fetchUser(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping (Result<UserModel, Error>) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
        .document(uid)
        .getDocument { snapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error ?? FirestoreErrorCode(.notFound)))
                return
            }

            do {
                let user = try snapshot.data(as: UserModel.self)
                completion(.success(user))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
}
```

With completion handlers, you want to make sure every path of execution calls the completion handler closure. (As an aside, that nil-coalescing operator, `??`, with `.notFound` probably is not needed, because I believe that if `snapshot` is `nil`, there must be an `error`, but I always try to be defensive in my error handling code.)

Anyway, you would then have a `switch` statement on the result:

```swift
fetchUser(withUid: uid) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        // update UI with `error` here

    case .success(let user):
        // use `user` here
    }
}
```

For more information, see [Writing Failable Asynchronous APIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/writing-failable-asynchronous-apis).

---

The `async` rendition could be simplified to:

```swift
func fetchUser(withUid uid: String) async throws -> UserModel {
    try await Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .document(uid)
        .getDocument()
        .data(as: UserModel.self)
}
```

As you can see, there is no need for any `do`-`catch` blocks in the above, if all you plan on doing is rethrowing the error. The `try` will automatically throw the error for you.

Anyway, you can then call it with:

```swift
do {
    let user = try await fetchUser(withUid: uid)
    // use `user` here
} catch {
    // update UI with `error` here
}
```

Comment: You used `guard let snapshot` in place of `guard let snapshot = snapshot`. Was this always a thing in Swift? I never knew this shorthand existed.

Comment: @trndjc - It’s a relatively recent addition, added in Swift 5.7. See [SE-0345](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0345-if-let-shorthand.md).